# Styling header in R tmap::tm_facets

Tags: r, style

I am generating some maps and animations with tmap, using [tm_facets](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tmap/versions/1.11/topics/tm_facets). 
The default style shows rather ugly grey headers for each small map. How can I change the **style of the header** (position, font size/family, background colour)?
[image]

```
tm_shape(Europe) +
    tm_polygons("well_being", title="Well-Being Index") +
    tm_facets("part", free.coords=FALSE) +
tm_style_grey()
```

Similar code snippets are available in the [R Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-nutshell.html).

Comment: Can you share your code that produces that set of faceted plots in your question? I don't think its one of the examples in help(tm_facet) (unless we're on different versions)...

Comment: Any example in the link above will do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `tm_layout(panel.label.X)` to change options:

```
library(tmap)

data(Europe)

tm_shape(Europe) +
  tm_polygons("well_being", title="Well-Being Index") +
  tm_facets("part", free.coords=FALSE) +
  tm_layout(panel.labels = c('facet1','facet2','facet3','facet4','facet5'),
            panel.label.size = 1.5, panel.label.color = 'white',
            panel.label.bg.color = 'blue', panel.label.height = 1.1,
            panel.label.rot = c(0,45))
```

[image]